# How can I get my camera app to take pictures with the sound of my voice?

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to create an app which uses the camera, which I believe I have up and running, I want to be able to say snap and it works as the shutter and takes a picture.... Any help would be great help.

Comment: you might want to accept some previous answers.. people will be more inclined to respond to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this is just guessing as it is not something I have done, but I have been reading up on voice recognition.

You'd probably need to press a button that would start a voice recognition intent or one of the speech recognition listeners... I can't find the page I saw it, but this is a starting point:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html

Then when it hears speech it will have to analyse it and check if it said "snap", then if it did take a photo.

I can imagine there will be some complications as there may be background noise and I'm not sure how it would handle it as I think the intent just sits there listening! 
It probably wouldn't be immediate either as I am pretty sure it has to send off to google to check what was said..

Starting at the page I gave have a dig around the developer docs and there an example there somewhere showing how to listen for speech, but I can't find it now I'm looking again.

I am curious what you find!